# java: use two version of the same lib in one webapp

Tags: java, jar, jaxb, version

I'm facing the following problem: I have one module in my webapp that needs jaxb 1.x and the other module needs jaxb 2.x. The first module doesn't work with the new version of jaxb, and the opposite. How can I use these two jars in one project?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by 'module in my webapp'. For example, are they separate ejb modules or are they just separate layers that share the same classpath? Also, can you list what the libs are that have the dependency on the JAXB jars?

Comment: You can think of module as of a lib(it's more complicated but at last I have jar files that are linked to my webapp via classpath). First one is docx4j.jar and the second one is third party helper for work with WebService. I can't change neither third part helper nor docx4j.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the JAXB reference implementation, then you can use your **JAXB 1** models with the **JAXB 2** runtime by including the **jaxb1-impl.jar**.

- http://jaxb.java.net/faq/index.html#running1Apps

Answer (score 5):

For a regular application, usually very different versions use different package names. If this is the case, you can use them both at once without problem.  However if they are the same, you can use [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to rename the package.

However since you are using a web container each application should use the version you deploy and not the other version. i.e. the web container works it out for you.

OSGi is another container which manages the versions much more explicitly and give you more control over these issues (however I believe you need it just for this)

Comment: Yes, I can rename the package for a jaxb 2.1 jar, but I don't want to do it. It's because the solution is a birt 'dirty'. OSGi yes, but only if there is no other solution... hm....renaming seems more and more suitable)

Comment: It is what the renaming functionality was added for. I have seen a single jar with four different versions of Xerces which you can select at runtime. :-P

Answer (score 2):

You have got a jar-hell issue. Generally speaking in normal java environment it's impossible to solve this problem. You have to force modularization into your project by using OSGI. Starting point: http://www.osgi.org/About/HowOSGi

Answer (score 1):

As Shaman said is imposible to resolve this issue.

Let's see: the servlet container JRE has only one classloader, and this classloader can load and use one class from jaxb or the other, but not both that will give you a classdefnotfound exception or something similar.

You can not solve this directly: 
you can get the code (is opensource) and change the package of one to another name so the classloader can use both. I do not recommend you this solution, is a bad one.

Better is that you migrate the code to use the most modern API (jaxb 2)

Comment: Can't do that. Because don't have all the sources. Is there a way to load new clases by myself? For instance, I put all the logic and dependencies into one jar and load it's main class. Then I call it's business methods. What will be if I do that?